# How to use Alamofire with Facebook Login?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, facebook-ios-sdk

After retrieving an access token from Facebook, I'm trying to use the token to connect with an OAth2 server.  When I try and connect I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized access code but when the backend developers connect it works. 
Here is the Curl from the backend developers that works:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "client_id" : "1",
    "access_token" : "EAARDjZAZBQnEEBAAxLZAE08npCWTeXUTQIHnP5rKx4poRZAlBAhL7UW6RJIUhZBmomIaIoNm97ERmVi0g2Ql5rfLZBckWf31hnOV6TCHkI8Tu4IBNknFBMsbaI8NvPl7aOp2qHhaAKaHx4UkwGJ9Eo8sZAaJhN7v0M7aCwNpUE3HgZDZD"
}' "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook"
```

Here is my alamo fire code:

```
func facebookAPILogin (fbAccessToken: String, completionHandler: (ErrorType?) -> ()) {


  let headers = [

    "Content-Type": "application/json"

  ]

  let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [

    "client_id" : "1",
    "access_token" : fbAccessToken

  ]


  Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(baseTestOathURL)facebook", encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .Success:
        print("Validation Successful")

        guard let value = response.result.value else {

          completionHandler(response.result.error)
          return
        }

        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(value)


          print("This is the FaceBook response \(swiftyJsonVar)")

        completionHandler(nil)

      case .Failure(let error):

        print("Sorry there was an error: \(error)")

         completionHandler(error)

        return
      }

      }

}
```

I can't figure out hwy I can't connect, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: JD hi can you tell me what is value for your \(baseTestOathURL) .How can we get this URL to make request.Is it the same as shown below "access_token" id?? I need to do facebook login using almofire and swifty json it seems like you have worked on it can you give a help?

Comment: Just saw your message, the baseTestOathURL is an internal url we use for all our API activity.  Through that URL we connect to facebook.

Comment: so that's is the actual name or it has some value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to pass the parameters.

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(baseTestOathURL)facebook", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot.  I spent so much time trying to figure this out and it was something so simple.

Comment: I like to use a proxy when doing networking so I have a rolling history of my requests. Helps with debugging. Look into Charles, its a pretty decent light weight one